# AdapterView<?> parent versus adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListView`. Naturally I pass an adapter to it, say `mDogAdapter`. My `ListView` also implements `setOnItemClickListener`.

So here is my question: in the context of getting an item from the adapter, what is the difference between these two?

```
Dog dog =(Dog) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
Dog dog = mDogAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: as you can see in the code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.getItemAtPosition%28int%29 no difference whatsoever.

Comment: There is a bit to note. If your question is in efficiency, you are adding a process when you use getItemAtpOsition(), as that process will then call getItem(position) which you could call directly from your adapter.

Comment: @zgc7009 so it is faster?! that's good to know.

Comment: At a very, very small level, yes it should be more efficient. But you would have to probably put your adapter through some pretty crazy strains for it to be anywhere near noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference.

The `AdapterView`'s `getItemAtPosition()` method will call `getItem()` on the adapter in its implementation.

It's up to you to decide which makes more sense.  If it's possible that you may use a different adapter at some point, you should consider using the `AdapterView`'s `getItemAtPosition()` method -- let the `AdapterView` deal with getting the correct data from its `Adapter`.